# Return which element matched each row in SQL result

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I am programmatically writing SQL queries from user input. I want to show the user for each row returned, which part of their supplied query information matched against that row.

For instance user supplied information looks like:

```
red:[11,202]
blue:[36]
green:[202]
yellow:[11,36]
```

This information would build the following query:

```sql
SELECT name, list FROM test WHERE list SIMILAR TO '%(11|202|36)%'
```

But I would like to add a result field similar to the "Matched Element shown below:

| name | list | Matched Element |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foobar | 15,11,19,20 | red, yellow |
| hello | 17,30,36,20 | blue, yellow |
| bar | 101,202,330,460 | red, green |
| test | 15,36,23 | blue |

I cannot add attempted examples as I do not know the proper language by which to seach for information. My current solution so far is to process the data row by row after the query has returned the result to my script to add the new column, but I would like to know if its possible to achieve this using postgres.

Here is a db-fiddle: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nMMB3wVFRTGeZgobmA4F6k/1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nMMB3wVFRTGeZgobmA4F6k/2)

I am running postgresql 12.3 however I am able to change version if needed.

Comment: Please describe the user input. Does the posted values indicate 4 separate inputs or a single input with new line separation. Is each a single string? Are the brackets physically present or indicators of an array?  ... Perhaps posting you line-by-line solution would be a benefit. It could at least show how you currently process the user input.

Comment: User input is multiple search strings, strings are categorised hence the red, green blue yellow. Original solution iterated returned rows and checks if the catogorised strings occur in the relevant column, if so then a new property is added to the row. Answer below have supplied great solutions without the need for further information so i will not post it to keep the question brief and meaningful to others. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Hambone that you should take advantage of arrays.  If you don't want to create an additional table, you could also do it all in one query:

```
select name, list,
  array_to_string(ARRAY[
      CASE WHEN list LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%11%', '%202%']) then 'red' else null end,
      CASE WHEN list LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%36%']) then 'blue' else null end,
      CASE WHEN list LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%202']) then 'green' else null end,
      CASE WHEN list LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%11%', '%36%']) then 'yellow' else null end
    ], ', ')
from test 
where list LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%11%', '%202%', '%36%', '%202%', '%11%', '%36%']);
```

Note that I'm using LIKE ANY instead of SIMILAR TO.  You could continue to use SIMILAR TO, but it seems easier to me to use LIKE ANY.

Here's a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nMMB3wVFRTGeZgobmA4F6k/3).

Comment: Perfect solution, obtains what I wanted in the query without a new table. Thank You.

Comment: Very creative!  One thing to be mindful of is if you have a value of "211" will "%11%" capture that in the result set?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you really need to take advantage of PostgreSQL's most excellent array support.  I feel like I say that a lot.

If you change your structure to arrays:

```
create table test2 (
  name varchar(255),
  list integer[]
)
```

Then, notionally you can even put your input into another table:

```
create table matches (
  color text,
  list integer[]
);

insert into matches values 
('red', '{11,202}'),
('blue', '{36}'), 
('green', '{202}'), 
('yellow', '{11,36}');
```

The following query should yield the results you seek:

```
select
  t.name, t.list, array_agg (m.color)
from
  test2 t
  join matches m on
    m.list && t.list
group by
  t.name, t.list
```

Comment: This is a great solution, however as it requires a new table and data to be inserted and presumably deleted on each user search the overhead puts me off a little. If the query data were already in the DB then it would be perfect. Thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can also consider a temp table...  I understand your concern.  I will say for the additional overhead, this is very scalable, and if there is a program wrapper this supports bind variables nicely compared to wildcard searches.